# jQuery:  .each how to reference matched object

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do i get a reference to the element that matched? 'this' is not correct.

For example here I am trying to alert with the elements value.

```
//how do i get this to reference the object it matches.
$("#txtFirstName,#txtLastName,#txtDOB").each(
    function() { alert(this.val()); }
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#txtFirstName,#txtLastName,#txtDOB").each(
    function() { alert( $(this).val() ); }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is `this`, but to use `val()` you need a jQuery object.

```
$(this).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

In that context `this` is a reference to the actual DOM element. You will need to wrap that into a jQuery object in order to use the `val()` function.

```
$(this).val()
```